# Threading/TPL etc

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-3.0, task-parallel-library

I have a requirement to process 16million database records and this is gonna take me forever. I am not threading savvy so thought I'd ask here. My thinking is that I need to perform the following but am unsure how:

1. Get my 16m records
2. split these out into a number of "chunks"
3. send each of these chunks for processing on their on thread

Does this sound right and how would I split my workload(16m records) up etc...?

Cheers if you can offer sound advice.

Comment: one question: you tagged this with TPL but also with C#3.0 - but the TPL came with .net4.0 - so you should be able to use C#4.0 - if so you might find this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-at/devlabs/gg585582 interesting

Comment: @CarstenKönig, TPL Dataflow is for more complicated flows. I don't think it would be useful in this case.

Comment: well ... IMHO this is a reasonable scenario

Comment: What kind of processing do you have to do? The best place to process a lot of database records is the database itself. Pulling the data out of the database and transporting it over the wire is very expenside.
TPL Dataflow simplifies flow processing. It is NOT only for complicated dataflows.

Comment: Cheers for all your input folks, Panagiotis Kanavos, I am taking DB record from database, building an XML file from the returned data and then uploading this XML file to Azure as a BLOb.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the well-known producer-consumer pattern in the following way:

- a single thread (the producer) pulls records from the db, creates tasks (with a single or maybe multiple records to process) and puts them in a shared queue.
- a group of threads (the consumers) pull tasks from the queue and process them in parallel.

A very simple way to implement this is using the `ThreadPool` class. It conveniently manages the queue and the workers for you. All you need is to implement the producer and queue tasks via `QueueUserWorkItem`.

Alternatively, if you want to use TPL constructs, you can implement the above mechanisms yourself using a combination of `Task`s and perhaps a `ConcurrentQueue`.

Comment: This is a bit confusing. The TPL constructs *are* an implementation of the Produces-Consumer pattern - ConcurrentQueue even implements the IProducerConsumer interface. To use ThredPool you have to implement the same mechanisms all over again.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to process a collection of items in parallel, that's exactly what [`Parallel.Foreach()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx) is for. You will just pass it an action that you want to perform for each item (possibly as a lambda) and it will take care of splitting your collection into chunks and executing it.

But you have to be careful about what you put into that action. That's because the code will be executed on more threads concurrently, so you shouldn't access any shared state in an way that is not thread-safe.